# Why is Ruby array.each do not iterating over each item in array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iteration

I'm new to ruby and rails and coding in general. But I'm working on a project that uses the steam web api to get a list of games owned by a user on steam. I'm trying to take that information and store it in my own table. I was able to get the information into my site but I need to select only one part of the information to pass into my table.

In my users controller I have this for show:

```
 def show
     #renders the user page
     @user = User.find(params[:id])
     @player = SteamWebApi::Player.new(@user.steam_id)
 end
```

In the users show view I have this:

```
<% user_class = User.new %>
<h2> These are the games you own </h2>
<% @games = @player.owned_games %>
<% @steam_game_ids = user_class.get_steam_id_from_games(@games) %>
<br>
<%= user_class.check_if_games_exit_in_table(@steam_game_ids) %>
```

The *@player.owned_games* gives an array of games like this:
[{"appid" => 1234}, "something" => 23123}, {"appid" =>...}]

In my users model I define these methods:

```
def get_steam_id_from_games(games)
    games.games.map{|x| x.values[0]}       
end

def check_if_games_exist_in_table(steam_ids)
    string_ids = steam_ids.map(&:to_s) #not converting to string
    string_ids.each do |app_id|
        if Game.exists?(game_app_id: app_id)
            return "this exists"
        else
            return "#{app_id} doesn't exist"
        end
    end       
end
```

*get_steam_id_from_games* makes an array with only the appid values for each game:[1234, 234545,..]

*check_if_games_exist_in_table* is supposed to take the appid array, converts the items to strings (that's how I store the information in my table), and then checks if there is an object in the table with the same appid.

This is where the problem is for me, the *string_ids.each to |app_id|* only goes through the first thing in the array. Is this because I'm returning "this exists" or "doesn't exist"? What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score -2):

```
def check_if_games_exist_in_table(steam_ids)
 string_ids = steam_ids.map(&:to_s) #not converting to string
 array_of_non_existing_ids = []
 string_ids.each do |app_id|
   if !Game.exists?(game_app_id: app_id)
      array_of_non_existing_ids.push app_id  
   end
 end
 return "#{array_of_non_existing_ids.join(',')} doesn't exist" if array_of_non_existing_ids.any?

 return "this exists"
end
```

Comment: This code, evaluate which ids do not exist and add them inside the array "array_of_non_existing_ids", them asks to return  an error with the list of non existing ids in a string if "array_of_non_existing_ids" have at least 1 id inside.
if "array_of_non_existing_ids" is empty, them it returns "this exists".